# Default anchor action with Marionette Routing

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, url-routing, marionette

I have a Marionette application that is composed of a series of steps, each step corresponding to a different view, each with an anchor tag in a navigation bar.

```
<a href="#toolbox">Select Tools</a>
<a href="#payment">Pay</a>
```

My current struggle is finding the best way to structure the URLs so that the `Marionette.AppRouter` can respond to them. Whenever I use a scheme like `href="/toolbox"`, the page just tries to navigate away to that URL (bypassing the router), unless I prevent the default action of the anchor. Should I be using a fragment scheme like `href="#toolbox"`? Or, should I be setting up my `Backbone.history.start()` call differently? What is the best practice here?

Comment: <a href="#!/toolbox">Select Tools</a> This is how i write all my hrefs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is use "#toolbox" as the `href`, but I still call `preventDefault` on the click event.

That way:

- the app handles the navigation, and simply updates the URL fragment
- the user can open a link in a new window (or load a bookmark) and land on the expected page (because the route gets triggered by the routing controller)

Essentially, once a route has been loaded and the user is "inside" your Marionette app, routes shouldn't be triggered anymore. Instead controller actions should be called via events to udpate the app's display. More on this approach to routing here (see section "Implementing Routing"): http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight, David. I had never thought of routing as an entry point only. Great answer!

Comment: No problem, the idea comes from Derick Bailey (Marionette's creator): http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/ Designing your app with this in mind is very helpful to keep complexity manageable...